# Symfony does not cache changes on controllers

Tags: php, symfony, caching, controller

I use Symfony 2.8.

I modified a controller file and I loaded the changes on the production server, I can see the changes without the need to use `php app/console cache: clear` and without use `app_dev.php`.

If I modify a Twig file everything does not happen and I have to clean the cache to transport the changes from `app_dev.php` to production environment.

why?

Comment: Caching Twig templates is about saving them in form of parsed to pure PHP code. How would cached controller be different than not cached?

Comment: I have imagined that symfony the first use of a file it would record in the cache without going to read "the original" in order to maintain a development environment completely separate from production.
I found little documentation on the cache works in symfony, if you know help me would be very grateful.

Comment: Double check that you have php's opcache enabled in production. Modifying a controller file won't have a cache associated as php simply reads the file from disk when opcache is disabled. Twig has a compilation step, thus this needs triggering.

Comment: @SimoneMarchiori cached (parsed) Twig templated a saved to simple php files on disk. Cachinng controllers this way doesn't make sense. Actually there are many possible levels o caching, therefore it's a bit too broad topic to discuss here.

Comment: @SimoneMarchiori also you didn't find a lot about caching in Symfony docs, because it's distributed knowledge. Caching data that belongs to 3rd party libraries (like Twig or Doctrine) is out of scope of Symfony's docs. Also in Symfony there are a few mechanisms for caching different things in different ways.

Comment: So when I run "php app/console cache: clear " on a Symfony application i'm deleting different cache of different components of symfony?

Comment: So what's the point of using app_dev.php on the same production server if some files it caches and others not? No danger of mix old files cached (es twig) with updated files not cached (controllers)  in production server before run cache:clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controllers aren't cached in Symfony. There is no time consuming logic involved in reading controllers (it's just PHP code anyway).

When deploying to production server, always make sure to clear the cache using the `cache:clear` command. Also make sure to remove the `app_dev.php` file and any other, not used, PHP file in the `web/` directory. You shouldn't run the dev environment on the production server.